# How to hide the values in terraform plan/apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I'm creating a new module with aws_ssm_parameter, but when I run the terraform plan it returns the added values ​​and not the parameter name.

Output after **terraform plan**:

```
    Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.parameter.aws_ssm_parameter.parameter["Variable-Sensitive-1=12345,Sensitive-Variable-2=67890"] will be created
  + resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "default" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + data_type = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + key_id    = (known after apply)
      + name      = "/dev/parameter-development/test"
      + overwrite = true
      + tags      = {
      +      env = "Development"
        }
      + tier      = "Standard"
      + type      = "SecureString"
      + value     = (sensitive value)
      + version   = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

**Module Configuration:**

main.tf

```
locals {
  parameter = { for e in var.parameter : e.value => merge(var.parameter_defaults, e) }
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "default" {
  for_each = local.parameter

  name     = each.value.name

  description     = each.value.description
  type            = each.value.type
  tier            = each.value.tier
  value           = each.value.value
  overwrite       = each.value.overwrite
  allowed_pattern = each.value.allowed_pattern
  tags            = var.tags
}
```

**Variables:**

variables.tf

```
variable "parameter" {
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = []
}

variable "parameter_defaults" {
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    description     = null
    type            = "SecureString"
    tier            = "Standard"
    overwrite       = "true"
    allowed_pattern = null
  }
}
```

Enviroment Development:

```
module "default" {
  source          = "../../module/default"

  parameter = [
    {
      name        = "/dev/parameter-development/test"
      value       = "Variable-Sensitive-1=12345,Sensitive-Variable-2=67890"
      type        = "SecureString"
      overwrite   = "true"
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    env = "Development"
  }
}
```

How can I hide these sensitive values?

Is there something wrong with the way I set it up?

Comment: You could use the sensitive option. https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-14-adds-the-ability-to-redact-sensitive-values-in-console-output

Comment: Change `e.value` to be `e.name`. It doesn't make sense to be accessing the resource index you loop over by the value and instead makes more sense by the name even if it wasn't sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks, bro! This was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your Terraform's plan and apply are showing the sensitive values because you are using them as part of the [resource address](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/state/resource-addressing.html).

You can't hide this in any way, even if the field itself is [considered and marked as `sensitive`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#suppressing-values-in-cli-output) because the resource address is so important to how Terraform works with its [resource graph](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/graph.html) and there's generally an expectation that the resource addresses should be considered non sensitive.

More importantly, however, it doesn't actually make sense to address these resources by the sensitive value and you could instead address them by the name of the parameter instead of the value and still achieve the same looping mechanism and this would also have the benefit of hiding your sensitive values.

You can do this by changing your looping [`each` object](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html#the-each-object) to reference the name instead:

```
locals {
  parameter = { for e in var.parameter : e.name => merge(var.parameter_defaults, e) }
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "default" {
  for_each = local.parameter

  name     = each.value.name

  description     = each.value.description
  type            = each.value.type
  tier            = each.value.tier
  value           = each.value.value
  overwrite       = each.value.overwrite
  allowed_pattern = each.value.allowed_pattern
  tags            = var.tags
}
```

Where we've only changed `e.value` to `e.name` and left everything else as it is.